# Getting a unix timestamp as a string in C++

Tags: c++, timestamp

I'm using the function time() in order to get a timestamp in C++, but, after doing so, I need to convert it to a string. I can't use ctime, as I need the timestamp itself (in its 10 character format). Trouble is, I have no idea what form a time_t variable takes, so I don't know what I'm converting it from. cout handles it, so it must be a string of some description, but I have no idea what.

If anyone could help me with this it'd be much appreciated, I'm completely stumped.

Alternately, can you provide the output of ctime to a MySQL datetime field and have it interpreted correctly? I'd still appreciate an answer to the first part of my question for understanding's sake, but this would solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`time_t` is some kind of integer. If `cout` handles it in the way you want, you can use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to convert it to a string:

```
std::string timestr(time_t t) {
   std::stringstream strm;
   strm << t;
   return strm.str();
}
```

Comment: Assuming time_t is an integer is not really a good idea in regards to portability: "Portable programs should not use values of this type directly, but always rely on calls to elements of the standard library to translate them to portable types." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it as follows:

```
char arcString [32];
std::string strTmp;

// add start-date/start-time
if (strftime (&(arcString [0]), 20, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S", (const tm*) (gmtime ((const time_t*) &(sMeasDocName.sStartTime)))) != 0)
{
    strTmp = (char*) &(arcString [0]);
}
else
{
    strTmp = "1970-01-01_00:00:00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sprintf(string_variable, "%d", time)` or `std::string(itoa(time))`?

Comment: This allowed the process timestamp to be printed, but it always returns 134515192. specifically, my code is:

char timestamp[10];
sprintf(timestamp, "%d", time);

then later

query += timestamp

query being an std::string.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=231056

In the end `time_t` is just an integer.